# Configurable Product Blank Page

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am trying to set up a configurable product but all I get when I click on the product is a **completely** blank page. No header, etc, nothing. View Source shows no code is output at all.
What could be causing this?
Here is the url to the configurable product: 
https://www.design-a-cake.co.uk/photocake-edible-cake-topper-pumpkin-lanterns.html
Thank you.

Comment: it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

Your page has no error: see screenshot below

[image]

So in short, your issue seems to  be that the rendering does seem to  be stopped somehow. To debug, you may go in the product controller and put some logs to check what's happening. If you have installed some plugins, you may look at a possible controller taking over product in your Magento system.

Comment: I enabled errors to display and output the location of the files to better assess where the errors were coming from. Now I just get a warning (unrelated to page load) and still a blank screen. I have no idea how to see what it stopping the page from rendering.